# Wrong timing in physics simulation with piston

Tags: rust, simulation, game-development, rust-piston

I have written a very basic simulation of a pendulum. I used the equation `α = -g/l * sin(φ)`. I set `g/l` to 50, so I expect to get a period of 0.89 seconds (Using the formula `2π*√(l/g)`). However, I get a period of around 6.5 seconds. The relevant code part is

```
let ang_acc = - 50.0 * pendulum.angle.to_radians().sin();
pendulum.ang_vel += ang_acc * dt;
pendulum.angle += pendulum.ang_vel * dt;
```

The complete code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/marchersimon/pendulum). I tried to make it as basic as possible and commented everything important.

Comment: Your acceleration and velocity are in radians, but your angle is in degrees. You're missing a call to `to_degrees` somewhere.

Comment: Which is why "I set g/l to 50" sounded like a red flag - when doing any simulation work, you have to always keep units in mind. With angles, even more so.

Comment: The general recommendation is to keep everything in radians, and only convert from/to degrees directly from user input or directly before output to the user.